# Using remote spring beans

Tags: java, spring, war, rmi, ear

I have an EAR that includes services which will be exposed via Spring RMI. These services will be consumed in the front end layer, this layer will be packaged in a separate WAR file. All the services are spring beans and I'm using a jboss server.

My question is, how can I start the EAR application context remotely so the WAR file can use those beans? Any help or suggestion?

Comment: what do you mean by remotely. Are you talking over HTTP/ftp or LAN or a file system accessible to the ear

Comment: each one is installed in a different server istance